# Finding a class belonging to parent in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, hover

Trying to move some divs using hover, this is my markup:

```
<div class="item dark-grey">
    <div class="img">
        <img src="images/case-study-develop.jpg" width="174" height="59" alt="Case Study">
    </div>
    <div class="triangle-container">
        <div class="triangle-border-light-blue"></div>
        <div class="triangle-dark-grey"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content light-blue">
        <h2><a href="#">Developing community work with the voluntary sector</a></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I am using at the moment, which works fine but I only want the hover on the content div, not the whole item div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.item').hover(function(e){
                    $('.img', this).animate({height: "30px"},100);
            },function(e){
                    $('.img', this).animate({height: "58px"},100);
            });
    });
```

I thought if I hover over .item .content and then get the parent, and find .img belonging to the parent it would work, but am not sure if I am doing it right.

```
$('.item .content').hover(function(e){
                $(this).parents('.img').animate({height: "30px"},100);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have won't work because `.img` isn't a parent of `.content`, it's a sibling.

You can check the `siblings()` of `.content()`:

```
$('.item .content').hover(
    function(e){
        $(this).siblings('.img').animate({ height: "30px" }, 100);
    },
    //function...
});
```

Or you can traverse up the DOM to the parent of `.content` and then `find('.img')`:

```
$('.item .content').hover(
    function(e){
        $(this).parent().find('.img').animate({ height: "30px" }, 100);
    },
    //function...
});
```

Or if you can guarantee that the structrue of these divs will never change, you can use `prev()`:

```
$('.item .content').hover(
    function(e){
        $(this).prev().prev().animate({ height: "30px" }, 100);
    },
    //function...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want this:

```
$('.item .content').hover(function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.item').find('.img').animate({height: "30px"}, 100);
}, function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.item').find('.img').animate({height: "58px"}, 100);
});
```

This will watch for hover on the `.content` object and when the hover event happens, it will find the `.item` container and then find the `.img` object in that container and animate it.

One of the keys here is `.closest()` which finds the first ancestor that matches a given selector which is really useful for finding a specific container div.

Answer (score 1):

The `<img />` isn't a parent of the `.item .content` element, so you can't use that.

You can navigate to the `.item` element using `closest()` and then get the `.img` element from there;

```
$(this).closest('.item').children('img').animate({height: "30px"},100);
```

Although, as the `.img` element is a sibling of the `.item .content` element you could do;

```
$(this).siblings('.img').animate({height: "30px"},100);
```

For more info, see the [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) and [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).parent().find('.img')
```

should work